# How can i used subsery to update column

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an `EMPLOYEE` table below:

```
EMP_ID     DEPT_ID
101        1
102        2
103        3
104        1
```

And a `DEPARTMENT` table as:

```
DEPT_ID  COUNTS
1   
2   
3
```

I want to write a query which would count the number of `Employee` that belong to a department and store it into `Department` column table so the `Department` table will look like:

```
DEPT_ID  COUNTS
1         2
2         1
3         1
```

I tried:

```
update department p
set p.counts = (select count(*) from EMPLOYEE e where p.dept_id = e.dept_id
group by e.dept_id)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't tag spam.

Comment: Which DBMS did you use?Mysql or Oracle?

Comment: what is the error? did you put commit after you run update? Your query looks clean. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9d214/1

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `group by` and the first alias:

```
update department p
    set counts = (select count(*) from EMPLOYEE e where p.dept_id = e.dept_id);
```

Comment: First query does not work on oracle, it fails at "FROM department d" with error SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended and I did not quiet understand how second query works. How does it know which dept ids in DEPARTMENT it has to set counts to. what exactly does this subquery return "select count(*) from EMPLOYEE e where p.dept_id = e.dept_id"